# Android Microsoft Ergonomic 4000 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb-peripherals, external-keyboard

Has any tried hooking up a Microsoft Ergonomic 4000 keyboard to a Android device. It doesn't seem to work with my Sony Xperia Table S (Android 4.0.3). However with my Raspberry PI it works like a charm. I haven't tried installing Android yet on my Raspberry but hoping someones knows something about it. I have not been able to find anything on Google about this.

Comment: There many reasons the keyboard wouldn't work the main reason would be a driver problem. Clearly the Linux disto your using on your Raspberry Pi supports the driver that allows the keyboard to function. Android isn't Linux.

Comment: Any change such a driver can be installed? I don't know a lot about Android.

Comment: @Ramhound Android is a Linux distro...

Answer (score 0):

As long as your Android device supports USB keyboards at all, any USB keyboard will work.  Many Android devices don't support working as a USB master device (due to hardware limitations), but running Android on a Raspberry Pi should work fine as its USB ports are fully-featured.

Comment: I have tried other keyboards and they do work. So it seems more a software problem then a hardware problem.

Comment: @DaveKok It could also be a power consumption problem, then. I see no reason why a conforming USB keyboard would have a software-level problem with working on a device where other conforming USB keyboards work.

Comment: Hmm, not really sure how to rule out power consumption, but thanks.

Comment: You could hook it up to a computer and see what its maximum reported current draw is (OSX and Linux both have tools for that, and Windows probably does too). Those numbers aren't trustworthy but it's a start. If you're handy with a multimeter and don't mind modifying a USB extension cable you can measure the current draw directly, as well.